# Jquery select and replace with check mark only one table row's radio input at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

Hi i just trying to figure out laravel foreach loop on a table. I want to when radio input selected changed with a check mark and background color green. If select other radio input, old input unchecked and selected check mark. It will continue like this for each radio input.

```
<table class="table">
  @foreach ($iterable as $key)
  <tr>
    <td>$key['name']</td>
    <td>
      <input id="id$key['id']" type="radio" name="inputs" value="val$key['id']">
      <label for="id$key['id']">Select</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

I changed radio buttons views with like a buttons.

```
.table input[type="radio"] {
    /* display: block; */
    /* position: absolute; */
    opacity: 0.01;
    z-index: 100;
  }

  .dable label {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 90;
  }

  .table label:hover {
    background: #DDD;
  }
```

I have it below but something missing. So how can do it with jquery?

```
    $(function(){
  $(".table input[type='radio']").on("change", function(){
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked').length;
    var label = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']");
    $(this).each(function(index) {
      if(isChecked < 1){
        $(label).html("<span>Select</span>").css('background', 'white');
      }else{
        $(label).html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i>").css('background', 'green');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Its is very unclear what are you trying to achieve...

Comment: @ikiK when I click to radio button it will show ✓ with green background. Other input's labels will reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.length` from `var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked').length;`
That was giving you `undefined`, if you just leave it, it gives you `true` and make that your  `if` condition.

You are making mistake in changing labels `innnerHTML` with `icon`, because you will have trouble setting it back.

Instead set it to `display none`, and append icon to closest `td`.

Script does now 4 things on click:

1. Show all `labels` (in order to show previously removed)
2. Remove all `icons` (in order to remove previously append)
3. Adds icon on closest `td` of wanted `label`
4. Hide wanted `label`

You can not condition this with `else` in `if` because clicking radio will always produce `true`, so your `else` will never fire.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".table input[type='radio']").on("change", function(){
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var label = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']");
    $(this).each(function(index) {
      if(isChecked === true){ 
      $("label").css('display', '');
      //show all labels
      
      $(".icon").remove();
      //remove all icons
      
      $(label).closest( "td" ).append( '<span class="icon">icon</span>');
      // add icon on clicked label closest <td>
      
       $(label).css('display', 'none');  
       // hide clicked label on clicked label
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.table input[type="radio"] {
    /* display: block; */
    /* position: absolute; */
    opacity: 1.01;
    z-index: 100;
  }

  .table label {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 90;
  }

  .table label:hover {
    background: #DDD;
  }
.icon{
background-color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
 
  <tr>
    <td>$key 1</td>
    <td>
      <input id="1" type="radio" name="inputs" value="1">
      <label for="1">Select 1</label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>$key 2</td>
    <td>
      <input id="2" type="radio" name="inputs" value="2">
      <label for="2">Select 2</label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>$key 3</td>
    <td>
      <input id="3" type="radio" name="inputs" value="3">
      <label for="3">Select 3</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also remove `label variable` and use `this`  this will react only to clicked element, and then you find `$(this).siblings( "label" )` or `$(this).closest( "td" )` and do something with it.

```
$(function(){
      $(".table input[type='radio']").on("change", function(){
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        
        //var label = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']");
        
        $(this).each(function(index) {
          if(isChecked === true){ 
          $("label").css('display', '');
          //show all labels
          
          $(".icon").remove();
          //remove all icons
          
          $(this).closest( "td" ).append( '<span class="icon">icon</span>');
          // add icon on clicked label closest <td>
          
           $(this).siblings( "label" ).css('display', 'none');  
           // hide clicked label on clicked label
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really good explain what I have to do.

Comment: @officialmmt Np, you should consider accepting this answer so it marks the question as solved.